# Control hover color

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

Sorry, this is kinda beginner question but I'm not getting through.
I have a Windows Forms Applicaton with 4 panel controls on it. Now I want that the panels change their background when the user hovers with the mouse. I have tried following:

```
private void Panel1_MouseIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.BackColor = Color.Red;
}

private void Panel1_MouseOut(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
}
```

That is working fine, but because I have 4 panels and not one I would have to add 6 more functions like this... The I tried to make one single function for all of them but event sender does not have an accessible BackColor property.

Is there a way to make one single MouseIn function for all panels?
If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YOu should cast it:

```
private void Panel_MouseIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Panel pan = sender as Panel;
  pan.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

And use this one function for all 4 panels as event handler

Answer (score 3):

You can cast your sender-object to a Panel like

```
Panel panel = (Panel)sender;
if(panel != null)
// Set the BackColor
```

Comment: why do you check it if it is null? A null sender can't generate events.

Comment: I check it to be sure not to access a non-panel-element. it can be that for example a button or something else wants to react on this event. 
It's a habit to check a cast object befor using it

Comment: ah ok, I just expect that the programmer doesn't handle button events with panel handler :)

Answer (score 3):

You should first cast the sender object to Panel :

```
Panel panel = sender as Panel;
if (panel == null)
    return;

panel.BackColor = Blue;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define an EventHandler for `MouseIn` and `MouseOut` and then

```
private void Panel1_MouseIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel p = sender as Panel;
    if(p == panel1){
        //set color  
    }
    else if(p == panel2){
       //set color
    }
...
}
```

The same for `MouseOut`

Comment: wrong, there is no need to do it for every panel. sender is a reference to the object which produced an event

Comment: Yeah, so you can use ONE event handler and inside that ONE eventhandler decide which color the particular panel should acquire.

Comment: looking on OP's code I might suggest that he is trying to change exactly one panel on MouseIn or MouseOut

Comment: @VladL Yes, I know. This is why you examine the sender. And the sender can only be one! So at most one panel will be changed.

Comment: so you do the if else for the case if different panels should have different colors on mouseIn?

Answer (score 0):

Inside mouse in and function remove all the code you have placed and write the one simple line of code below
And try it it will work

```
((Control)sender).BackColor = Color.Red;
```